How does decidability work in a semantic level?
In the Diagonal Argument : Cantor, Turing, Tarski and Lawvere video (link is with a timestamp), when the diagonal argument is explained in order to prove the Tarski's Undefinabiliy Theorem, an assumption is made that a "formula F can decide the truth of any statement". What does "decide" mean in this context? For example, say I have a truth predicate defined as follows:
def even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0
    
def odd(x):
    return x % 2 != 0

def true(f,x):
    return f(x) == True

How does true(even, 2) "decide" that it is a "yes" that 2 is even? It is just a bunch of symbols that have meaning under some interpretation (e.g. Python); there is no algorithm.

You can find the formal statement of Tarski's undefinability theorem on Wikipedia. It has little to do with decision in the algorithmic sense, so this phrasing is a bit misleading. It's more like F encodes, or defines the truth of a statement.

(Or perhaps decode is more appropriate, since it takes a code for a formula and outputs a formula.)

@NaïmFavier but in the video it then continues and says that "F(s,v) returns the truth value of a formula s applied on input v". How does it "return", again there needs to be an algorithm, no? I know representable formulas are recursive, but F doesn't need to be representable.

I also detect a circulus in probando, but quis sum?

https://robertcunningham.xyz/diagonalization/ Good approach to the diagonal lemma from a "programmer" perspective

The video explains it well. To transcribe it for those who don't watch it, the video starts with the assumption "Formula F can decide the truth of any statement," and defines/entails that as "F(s,v) return 'true' if the statement s applied on the variable v and 'false' otherwise." To clarify, they are saying that F would decide statements with one free parameter s by mechanically examining the structure of s to see whether it holds for a given v. One important nuance not well-captured by the video's presentation is that F takes in encoded representations of statements as natural numbers, and decodes them to statements in the same language used to express F.
The second part of your question is how a system like Python performs computation. The answer is that Python is defined in terms of a formal computational machine, often called the virtual machine of Python. If we were to attempt to give F in terms of Python expressions, we would actually be giving F in terms of instructions for Python's virtual machine.

So F (hypothetically) encodes an algorithm as an arithmetical formula?

@spacemonkey: Yes. Specifically, a proof of a theorem from some axioms showing some formulaic property is equivalent to a program which computes an output from some inputs by implementing some algorithm. For a bigger picture, see the computational trilogy.

But couldn't F, in theory, be defined as a wff that is not a theorem? I know that formulas which are theorems are recursive (what you said). Not sure about wffs in general.

@spacemonkey: That's not a bad question. We implicitly require F to have some structure; for example, we require it to express a ternary relation (relating two inputs to an output) and also a binary function (taking two inputs and returning an output). We're also assuming that it's a theorem because that's the only non-trivial case; if it's false or bogus then it can't mechanically implement truth. Tarski's point was that F doesn't exist regardless of theoremhood.

with wffs I was thinking about theories that are omega-incomplete, there is a formula which is true but not provable, for example in "GEB" D.H. gives ∀a:(0+a)=a that is not derivable in his system of arithmetic. But it is clearly true.

@spacemonkey: That's the connection between Gödel's incompleteness theorems and Tarski's result discussed in the video. Prior to Lawvere's theorem, they were seen as related but disconnected results; today, we see that Tarski's undefinability is the semantic complement to Gödel's incompleteness, which is only stated for some particular syntax and axioms. Gödel showed that no set of axioms would ever work, and Tarski showed that no metalogical approach could ever work even if it weren't axiomatic!
